# Large Video upload on Dropbox using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, django, angular, video, dropbox

I need to upload large video files on Dropbox using Angular 2/4. Dropbox api has a limit of 150 MB for Video files. For anything larger then this require splitting the video in chunks and then uploading it using upload session API's.

**1: First part of this question is that how should i split the video in chunks using JavaScript or Typescript?**

**2: Is it a good idea to upload it from the front-end? Or should i move the logic to backend (Django)?**

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js  - it is an html5 file upload library that handles chunking of large files

Comment: Thanks @glendaviesnz . Looking into it. I think its implementation for angular 2 isn't stable yet.